# Ideal postgres dictionary for Greek or Hebrew

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgres-9.6

I'm planning on using postgres 9.6 for FTS on both the Greek and Hebrew languages.

My question is: what is the ideal postgres dictionary to use and why?  Currently I'm planning on using a copy of simple with unaccent.

In my case I'm able to map any word to the root lemma form and search on that so its already sort of stemmed, I'm just mostly curious if anyone knows which dictionary might be ideal and why.

Thanks!

Comment: Upon some further investigation, ispell is looking pretty promising too.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I ended up just getting by quite well with just an english dictionary – in my case I have all the lemmas for each word of my dataset, so I can map each word and find things – my next step of exploration was to try something like ispell with greek but that looked like a pain in the neck and my results were good enough.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?